# C# how to retry if await url.GetStringAsync null?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I want to ask about how to retry if `await url.GetStringAsync` get cancel task?

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var httpclient = new HttpClient();
var html = await httpclient.GetStringAsync(url);
```

Comment: Easy, just call your method again. Also make an attempt at something and post it here.

Comment: Maybe consider having a look at the [Polly framework](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly). You can creat Policies for retries and much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wish to do so in the code above (rather  than using the `HttpResponse` object)
then you could do something like below

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var httpclient = new HttpClient();
int retries = 5;
int count = 0;
var html = await httpclient.GetStringAsync(url);

while(String.IsNullOrEmpty(html) && count++ < retries) {
    var html = await httpclient.GetStringAsync(url); }

if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(html)) {
    throw new Exception("Could not contact the server"); }
```